# Commas after a scanf statement?

Tags: c++, scanf, comma-operator

Not my code, but from [here](http://www.infoarena.ro/job_detail/144253?action=view-source). In the read_data() function there is a scanf with something after it I haven't see before. What does it do? Is it STL?

```
scanf("%d %d\n", &a, &b), G[a].pb(b), deg[b]++;
```

Comment: What is the source of confusion? The [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator)?

Answer (score 7):

This is a use of the comma operator. The comma operator, which is used fairly uncommonly, sequences together a bunch of expressions together as a single expression. In this case, the statement

```
scanf("%d %d\n", &a, &b), G[a].pb(b), deg[b]++;
```

means "do the `scanf`, then call `pb(b)` on `G[a]`, then call `deg[b]++`, evaluating to the result of `deg[b]++`.

I see that it's used in this context:

```
for(i = 1; i <= M; i++)
    scanf("%d %d\n", &a, &b), G[a].pb(b), deg[b]++;
```

Honestly, this strikes me as poor style. It would be better to write this:

```
for(i = 1; i <= M; i++) {
    scanf("%d %d\n", &a, &b); 
    G[a].pb(b);
    deg[b]++;
}
```

The above code is functionally equivalent and a lot more readable - you don't have to post to Stack Overflow or know weird details of the C++ language to figure out what it means. :-)

Answer (score 3):

It's just multiple expressions made into a single statement by using [*comma* operator.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator)
It helps to avoid the braces around the `for` loop (which is *not* a good idea in my opinion as it obfuscates the code).

It's functionally equivalent to:

```
   for(i = 1; i <= M; i++) {
        scanf("%d %d\n", &a, &b);
        G[a].push_back(b); /* after macro expansion */
        deg[b]++;
   }
```